# How to make text disappear when TextBox is within template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, controltemplate

I knew how to make text disappear while writing: we should use `GotFocus` `LostFocus`.
For the example I did it with this `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchNotes" Foreground="Gray" 
         Text="Search" LostFocus="NoteBox_OnLostFocus"
         GotFocus="NoteBox_GotFocus" BorderThickness="0" 
         Background="WhiteSmoke" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
         Width="771"
         />
```

Here is the code:

```
public void NoteBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchNotes.Text = "";
    SearchNotes.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}

public void NoteBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchNotes.Text = "Search";
    SearchNotes.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
}
```

Now, I am trying to do the same thing with another `TextBox`, but the problem is that the `TextBox`is within a `Window` template so I don't have access to this `TextBox` from code (or I don't know how to access it)

This is XAML code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="WindowTextbox" GotFocus="WindowTextbox_GotFocus" LostFocus="WindowTextbox_LostFocus" Text="Type..." TextChanged="WindowTextbox_TextChanged" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" Background="#404040" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0 0 0 23">
</TextBox>
```

When I am trying to access this from code I can't:

[image: Error, the WindowTextBox is not found.]

So I wanna know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the `sender` parameter is for, see [Routed Events Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

> The object where the handler was invoked is the object reported by the `sender` parameter.

```
private void WindowTextbox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   textBox.Text = "";
   textBox.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}

private void WindowTextbox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   textBox.Text = "Search";
   textBox.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
}
```